# Measuring effectiveness of debt reminders

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, finance

I am working for a bank that reminds its customers that they owe money back periodically starting from 3 days before their credit deadline, on the day of the deadline, 3 days after the deadline, a week after the deadline, etc. The reminders are text messages and voice calls. I have to check how effective the each text message and call is. I have all the possible data. There is no alternative group (customers that do not get reminders). What is the best methodology for this project? I was thinking on doing an interrupted time series, however there are would be too many interruptions, as there are many events taking place. Any input will be of help.

Comment: If you have no control how do you hope to find out the effect of reminders? You do not know how the group with no reminders would behave.

Comment: You can draw an expected line and see how much it deviates from the expected.

Comment: And how do you obtain this expected line?

Comment: There are many methods - moving average, weighed average, arima, sarima...

Comment: But this is still based on the same data, customers who received reminders?

Comment: Yes, this is basically what an interrupted time series is. You calculate the trend before the reminder and see if the reminder changes it significantly. My issue is that there are many events (reminders) and I'm not sure an interrupted time series is the best option.